# Regular expression in PowerShell for tranforming lines with "TRN"

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0

I need help with figuring out the regular expression for the PowerShell script.  The data could look like the following:

```
TRN    ABCD;
TRN ABCEDFG;
TRN    HIJ ;
TRN   KLMNO  XXXXX ;
TRN      XYZ                ;
```

I need to select the data between `TRN` + spaces and before either a `space` or "`;`".

So my output should be:

```
ABCD
ABCEDFG
KLMNO
HIJ
XYZ
```

However, the `TRN` can be preceded by one or more empty lines and I can't figure out the regular expression for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 (gc myfile.txt | select-string -Pattern '(?<=trn\s+)([^\s]+)(?=\s|;)' ).matches.value
```

Comment: To whomever downvoted my question, I spent a good 4 hours trying to figure it out, the best I had was '\A(?:\s*)(?:TRN\s+)(.*?=\s+?)(?=\s+|;)', but that wasn't working for the "trailing" values before the ';'.  I didn't want to post it, since I figured it might be even more confusing...